# using aggregation function while creating function in psql

Tags: postgresql, function, psql

Hi guys i have little problem, i have tables like those

```
CREATE TABLE client(
    regon VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    title VARCHAR, 
    phone VARCHAR, 
PRIMARY KEY(regon));

CREATE TABLE commodity(
    id_com INT NOT NULL, 
    title VARCHAR, 
PRIMARY KEY(id_com));

CREATE TABLE supply(
    regon VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES klient(regon), 
    id_supply INT NOT NULL, 
    id_com INT NOT NULLREFERENCES commodity(id_com), 
    quantity INT, 
    price DEC(5,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(regon, id_supply, id_com));
```

and i have to create function which would returns value of all supplies (qantity*price)
and i made function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION value1(out id int, out war double precision)as $$                                                  
    select (quantity*price) as value from supply;
$$             
language 'plpgsql';
```

but it only shows the first supply with id of first commodity with its value but not all commodities
maybe 
you know how to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `select (quantity*price) as value from supply;`
to this:

```
select sum(quantity*price) from supply
group by id_com
order by id_com
```

Comment: But then it calls me to group by also by quantity and price

Answer (score 0):

I had to do query like this:

```
select sum(quantity*price) from supply
    group by id_com,quantity,price
    order by id_com
```

and it is also showing me id_com double times like i have two commodities with id 1 and one is 400 and second is 30, and i think i should maybe sum this up

Comment: you cannot group by columns then get their sum, it is actually no different than doing `select quantity*price from supply`